# Regex to remove everything before and after the first <p> tag

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to get the content of the first p tag in a string (but without the actual tags).

**Example:**

```
<h1>I don't want the title</h1>
<p>This is the text I want</p>
<p>I don't want this</p>
<p>I also don't want this</p>
```

I guess I need to finde everything else and replace it with nothing? But how do I create the regex?

Comment: REGEX is not the right tool to parse HTML ! Use a proper parser. Are you using Linux shell ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @hwnd Vbscript (Same syntax as javascript)

Comment: @sputnick that's unfortunately not an option. I need to do this in vbscript.

Comment: Added vbscript code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern to capture what you want

```
^[\s\S]*?<p>([^<>]*?)<\/p>
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/134)

```
^               # Start of string/line
[\s\S]          # Character Class [\s\S]
*?              # (zero or more)(lazy)
<p>             # "<p>"
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^<>]         # Character not in [^<>]
  *?            # (zero or more)(lazy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
<\/p>           # "<\/p>"
```

---

or use this pattern to match everything else and replace with nothing

```
^[\s\S]*?<p>|<\/p>[\s\S]*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/135)

```
^               # Start of string/line
[\s\S]          # Character Class [\s\S]
*?              # (zero or more)(lazy)
<p>             # "<p>"
|               # OR
<               # "<"
\/              # "/"
p>              # "p>"
[\s\S]          # Character Class [\s\S]
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
$               # End of string/line
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
html.write fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.html").ReadAll
Set p = html.getElementsByTagName("p")
WScript.Echo p(0).innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it properly with a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

```
//p[1]/text()
```

Adapted from [Navigating XML nodes in VBScript, for a Dummy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723903/navigating-xml-nodes-in-vbscript-for-a-dummy) :

```
Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
objDoc.Load "C:\Temp\Test.xml"

' Find a particular element using XPath:

Set objNode = objDoc.selectSingleNode("//p[1]/text()")
MsgBox objNode.getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: How would that give me the content of the first p tag?

Comment: I tried your example with a few modifications, but the last line returns "Object required".

Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
objDoc.LoadXML(myHtmlString)
Set objNode = objDoc.selectSingleNode("//p[1]/text()")
response.write objNode.getAttribute("value")

Comment: HTML and XML are not the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822520/parsing-xhtml-with-xpath-using-microsoft-xmlhttp-in-vbscript just 2 seconds search !